# iFrame Vimeo code doesn't work the same in mobile

Tags: html, iframe, vimeo

I made a site using Readymag, with videos linked from Vimeo using iframe code. It's set up to autoplay without any visible controls - which works fine on desktop but on mobile it's just a still.

The website is maxolsonfilm.com

Used this code for the videos:

`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/873804593?background=1" width="900" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: I don't think embedded videos from sites like youtube or vimeo are allowed to autoplay. There may not be anything you can do about that if they don't allow it.  You can still tap it to play, right?